# Can I INSERT the result from a query INTO a new table with a TRIGGER?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a table named `Stadistics` which contains the data shown below:

```
date         hour   num_prodcuts 
--------------------------------
2019-01-16   12:42           3.2   
2019-01-17   13:40           4.2   
2019-01-17   14:32             3
```

Each time a row is inserted, I want to insert this query in a new table:

```
SELECT 
    date,sum(num_products) asum
FROM
    Stadistics GROUP BY date;
```

This query will show:

```
date         asum
-----------------

2019-01-16    3.2
2019-01-17    7.2
```

So I want to insert the sum of all `num_products` groped by `date` in a new brand table. I'm not sure if it possible to do this using triggers.

Can someone help me out with this? I will appreciate the help I'm really new to MySQL.

Comment: What leads you to believe that it's not possible to do?

Comment: Why do you want to store the data in a static table whereas you can easily obtain this data by shown simple query when you really need in this data? But if you do it by trigger you must check the target table for a record with the same `date` already exists, and if so update this record instead of insertion new one.

Comment: What do you want to happen with `UPDATEs` and `DELETEs`?  Perhaps this using a Trigger is risky in that these could lead to an incorrect sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to insert the sum of all num_products groped by date in a new brand table.

```
CREATE TABLE brand_new_table (...);

INSERT INTO brand_new_table
          (date, sum_products)
    SELECT date, SUM(num_products)
        FROM Stadistics
        GROUP BY date;
```

(Did you mean "Statistics" or "Sadistics"?)

In another sentence, you have another requirement:

> Each time a row is inserted ... Trigger

Yes, a Trigger could be used.  The `AFTER INSERT` Trigger code would include

```
INSERT INTO Stadistics
          (date, sum_products)
          VALUES
          (NEW.date, NEW.num_products)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          sum_products = sum_products + NEW.num_products;
```

By using IODKU, you automatically get a new row each day.  If the row already exists, then `sum_products` is increased.

Requirement:  You need one of these:

```
 PRIMARY KEY(date)
 UNIQUE(date)
```

so that it knows how to check for an existing row.

(See also Akina's Comments on this Answer.)

Comment: *The Trigger code would include* ??? you use OLD pseudotable, so the trigger is for UPDATE or DELETE action, not for INSERT action.

Comment: @Akina - Oops.  Changed it to `NEW` and specified which trigger.  (I guess the same use of `NEW` would work for `UPDATE`.)

Comment: I'd recommend to use `AFTER INSERT` trigger. It is possible that INSERT which fires the trigger will fail - but BEFORE trigger already have updated reference data. Integrity will be damaged in that case. *I guess the same use of NEW would work for UPDATE* In that case you must both add value from NEW and substract value from OLD.

Comment: @Akina - Some questions I should not try to answer.  I prefer not to use Triggers or FKs -- I prefer to have control over what is being done.  (So, I don't have much experience in writing them.)  Thanks for "getting my back".